# click event not working on hyperlink ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Jquery Click event on table hyperlink does not work for table data that comes from ajax call, yet it works for static data entered.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9mU4C/3/)

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    var txt = $(e.target).text().replace(/\s/g, "%20");
    alert(txt);

});
```

Comment: It seems the a tag is being created after the execuiton of your 

$('a').click(function(){}) try $(table).on('click','a',function(){})

jQuery on function bind an event on all future matching elements also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because you are adding data dynamically.

Use event delegation.

The `.on()` method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object.

Write:

```
$(".table").on("click","a",function (e) {
    var txt = $(e.target).text().replace(/\s/g, "%20");
    alert(txt);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/9mU4C/4/)

[Refer this document.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: +1. Good answer and the person who really understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `$(document).on("click", "a", function (e) {` instead of `$("a").click(function (e) {`

Answer (score 0):

use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) by jquery framework

it will work nice, if you do in such a way

```
$(document).on("click","selector",function(ev){
$(this)// your stuff..
});
```

as jquery doesn't bind events to dynamic content, so you need to parse the DOM again to find your element.